# How to use foreign key as composite key in EF Core 2?

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core, composite-primary-key, ef-core-2.0

I have several classes in EF Core 2. 
1) Class Ser

- has id as Guid type. It is a primary key, auto-incremented.

2) Class SerStaHis

- has SerId as Guid type. It is a foreign key to Class Ser. It is a primary key with timestamp
- has timestamp. It is a primary key with SerId

I use EF Core 2 to build two tables above. I have used Composite Key feature to combine SerStaHis.timestamp and SerStaHis.SerId as primary key.

I also use ForeignKey attribute in Class Ser.
The problem is I have managed to map the foreign key to Class SerStaHis, but I could not combine that foreign key with SerStaHis.timestamp as a primary key.

Here are code snippets for Class Ser, Class SerStaHis and OnModelCreating method.

```
public class Ser {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]   // auto-incrementing feature
    public Guid id { get; set; }

    //nav/foreign keys
    [ForeignKey("id")]
    public virtual ICollection<SerStaHis> SerStaHis{ get; set; }
}

public class SerStaHis{
    [Required] // maybe this is wrong as I got a foreign key from Class Ser
    public Guid service_id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // composite primary keys method. // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys
        modelBuilder.Entity<SerStaHis>()
            .HasKey(c => new {c.service_id, c.timestamp});
    }
```

Here is the actual result I got when I migrate to SQL:
[image: actual result]
<sub>(source: [pbrd.co](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HX0Iclv.png))</sub>

My expected result in SQL is as followed:[image: expected result]
<sub>(source: [pbrd.co](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HX0JJ8R.png))</sub>

Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Can I do the task above in FluentAPI method?

How do I use the foreign key as composite primary key?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
[ForeignKey("id")]
public virtual ICollection<SerStaHis> SerStaHis{ get; set; }
```

to

```
[ForeignKey("service_id")]
public virtual ICollection<SerStaHis> SerStaHis{ get; set; }
```

`ForeignKey` attribute works differently when applied on the FK property, reference navigation property and collection navigation property. When applied on collection navigation property, it specifies the FK property name of the *related* object.

I personally find `ForeignKey` attribute confusing and error prone. Fluent API is much more intuitive and provides much better control. The fluent configuration for your scenario is like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Ser>()
    .HasMany(ser => ser.SerStaHis) // collection navigation property
    .WithOne() // no reference navigation property
    .HasForeignKey(serStaHis => serStaHis.service_id); // foreign key property
```

Comment: how do I set the foreign key in serStaHis.service_id to be not nullable in both fluent api and attribute?

Comment: Value types (e.g. `Guid`, `int`, `DateTime` etc.) are always non nullable, so you don't need to set anything. If you have `string` or nullable type (`Guid?`, `int?` etc.) and for some reason you need to make it required, well, use `Required` attribute or `IsRequired` fluent API.